# split words,numbers from string and put it as 2D array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an string like`'[[br,1,4,12],[f,3]]'`. I want to split as strings and integers and put it into array like the string `[['br',1,4,12],[f,3]]`.
string maybe like `'[]'` or `'[[cl,2]]'`,ect...but the words only,`br`,`cl`,`f`and `i`. How does get the array. Any idea for this problem?
Thanks

Comment: always have it that similar structure?

Comment: Structure is similar but that is in string.i want the element as array format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do conversion that you wanted by using RegEx :

Get your string

```
var str = '[[br,1,4,12],[f,3]]';

str = str.replace(/([a-zA-Z]+)/g, '"$1"');    
console.log(str);

//Outputs :
[["brd",1,4,12],["f",3]]   // It is still just a string
```

If you wanted to convert it to object, you might use this :

```
var str = '[[br,1,4,12],[f,3]]';

function toJSObject(str){
  str = str.replace(/([a-zA-Z]+)/g, '"$1"');
  return (JSON.parse(str))
}

var obj = toJSObject(str);
```

Comment: Yes. That's correct. I want  convert it to object. Thank you.